# HTML: Identical files, different results. Yahoo vs Dreamweaver with Yahoo Store Tags

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-normalization, yahoo-merchant-store

I am building a store using Yahoo Store Tags. A yahoo store tag looks pretty much like an HTML comment:

```
<!--#ystore_catalog id="fsp0001" field="price" format="html" -->
```

Once it is on the server it is supposed to pull in the relevant field for the product ID. Here is the strange part. When I create a page in Dreamweaver, the Yahoo store tag does not work. If I create the HTML page in the Yahoo Webhosting file manager and paste in the exact same code from my Dreamweaver file (doctype, html tags and all) it does work. I can even download the file created in Yahoo, edit it in dreamweaver and send it back to the server and it works!

So is there an issue with how the files are being created in Dreamweaver? I tried to create a file using each of the different Unicode Normalization Forms but none of them work. What is Yahoo doing when it creates a file that Dreamweaver is not?

Here is a working page created in the Yahoo file manager (pulling in a price of $24.95): 
http://fullsteampress.com/pricetest2.html

Here is the same page created in Dreamweaver:
http://fullsteampress.com/pricetest.html

Here is the full HTML that was used in both pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--#ystore_catalog id="fsp0001" field="price" format="html" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Additional info:

On my computer it appears that the file created in dreamweaver is 374 bytes while the file create in the yahoo file manager is 670 bytes. Even when I open them up in a text editor the contents (my HTML) is identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this issue had nothing to do with file encoding but with the permissions of the files I was saving on my computer in Dreamweaver or TextEdit. It was saving as -rwxr--r--, I set cyberduck to change to -rwxrwxr-- on upload and now the store tags work.